# How to find cell containing non numerical character, in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have list of 16000 rows. In some rows there might be chinese characters, in that case I need to somehow make rows, that contain these chinese symbols distinctive (Like make them red, put "X" on end of the string, etc)

I  was thinking of creating formula, that checks if text only contains letters A-Z and number 0-9. If the condition is not met it add X to the name, or makes the row red... or something to distinguish it easily from the other rows.

I've tried searching the internet

Unfortunately I dont have any code, I dont have any idea how to get to my result

Row like
Ronnie Pet 9, will be untouched but row like
Ronnie Pet汉字 9, will be red, or the formula will add the X to its name
Ronnie Pet汉字 X 9

Thank you for your help

Comment: Would your strings contain question marks? Also any other non-ascii characters than the Chinese ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting to format the row.
One way is to test if the target cell has characters in the `CJK Unified Ideographs` range.

Depending on how the formula works out, you may need to also test for characters in the range of the various extensions. But you can use the same principal.

Conditional Format Formula (with cell to be tested in column A):

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(N(UNICODE(MID($A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A1))),1)) >= HEX2DEC("4E00"))),SUMPRODUCT(N(UNICODE(MID($A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A1))),1)) <= HEX2DEC("9FFF"))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! Thank you very much.To use it on other columns do I just replace A1 with C1 for example?

Comment: it says there is a error in my formula. But it Might be that I am using it in wrong way? I was trying to put the formula in empty cell

Comment: @Peter If that was the message when you entered it into some cell, then you made some inadvertent change other than merely changing the `A` to a `C`

Comment: I really just changed A to C and pasted the formula into an empty cell D1. Should this formula be put in "conditional formatting" window? Becuase when I put it there I dont get the error but it doesnt work also :(

Comment: @Peter And the message was **there is an error in your formula**?

Comment: @Peter If that, indeed, was the message, perhaps your settings are using semicolons for the separators and you neglected to make that change in the formula.

Comment: Yesm that was the message. The error message asked me if I want to place a formula and explained the difference between =1+1 and '=1+1. I've changed the formula to =AND(SUMPRODUCT(N(UNICODE(MID($B1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($B1)));1)) >= HEX2DEC("4E00")));SUMPRODUCT(N(UNICODE(MID($B1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($B1)));1)) <= HEX2DEC("9FFF")))). But get ?NAME error instead :(

Comment: Yes I did, all of them, but unfortunately I get the same result.=AND(SUMPRODUCT(N(UNICODE(MID($B1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($B1)));1)) >= HEX2DEC("4E00")));SUMPRODUCT(N(UNICODE(MID($B1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($B1)));1)) <= HEX2DEC("9FFF")))

Comment: @Peter what version of Excel?  What language version?

Comment: I have school licence for 365, and its in Czech language

Comment: @Peter then you need to translate the functions into Czech also.  According to the Excel translator, something like `= A (SUMPRODUCT (N (KÓD UNICODE (MID ($B 1; ŘÁDEK (NEPŘÍMÉ ("1:" & LEN ($B 1)); 1); > = HEX2DEC ("4E00")); SUMPRODUCT (N (KÓD UNICODE (MID ($B 1; ŘÁDEK (NENEPŘÍMÝ ("1:" & LEN ($B 1)); 1)) "< = HEX2DEC (" 9FFF ")))` might work.

Comment: Thank you very much I think there is problem somewhere in there. I have found out all the functions in Czech but still it doesnt work for me unfortunately,(No error but those rows are not highlighted too)  I have absolutely no idea why tho =A(SOUČIN.SKALÁRNÍ(N(UNICODE(ČÁST($B1;ŘÁDEK(NEPŘÍMÝ.ODKAZ("1:"&LEN($B1)));1)) >= HEX2DEC("4E00")));SOUČIN.SKALÁRNÍ(N(UNICODE(ČÁST($B1;ŘÁDEK(NEPŘÍMÝ.ODKAZ("1:"&DÉLKA($B1)));1)) <= HEX2DEC("9FFF")))

Comment: @Peter perhaps a problem with how you are entering it into the conditional formatting dialogue? I'm sure it is there as a formula and not as a text string. The dialogue sometimes adds quote marks around a formula

Comment: @Peter oh, and does it return true, false or a REF errror if in a worksheet cell?

Comment: It returns false

Comment: @Peter and does it return true if there is a Chinese character in the string in B1?

Comment: @Peter then you are doing something wrong when entering it into the conditional formatting dialogue. Exactly what I can't say from the information you've provided.

Comment: I'll try to tinker around with it. What I do is that I select the column, click on conditional formatting, paste the formula and hit enter. Really dont know what I could be doing wrong but still your code helps me a ton Ron! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @Peter If you don't figure it out, upload a sample workbook (`.xlsx` macro-free format) that demonstrates the problem to some public site, and post a link here. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest, I don't see why you couldn't use your original idea of checking that each character was in the list A-Z and 0-9:

```
=ISERROR(SUM(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),1),"0123456789 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")))
```

[image]

Comment: I think what to use depends on the data, since there might be characters that should not be flagged that are not in the set `[A-Za-z0-9]`.  Punctuation and non-Chinese characters come to mind.  With the precise nature of the data unknown, I felt it would be more robust to just look for the characters he stated he wished to exclude, rather than the opposite.  But if your assumption about the data is correct, your solution would be simpler.

Comment: I agree - your answer is safer and more specific, although it may be possible to take short cuts like mine in certain cases. Also I'm not sure about the ramifications of SEARCH vs SEARCHB in DBCS and non-DBCS languages.